# How to include two attributes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript in general and pretty much have no idea what is going on. Sorry for the super noobie question.

I have an accordion being started with the following code:

```
$(function(){
$("#accordion").accordion({header: "h3"});
});
```

But I have no idea where to include

```
autoHeight: false
```

Any general javascript beginner's guides would be much appreciated if you have any suggestions as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("#accordion").accordion({header: "h3", autoHeight: false});
});
```

Just separate all the attributes with a comma

Comment: I'm dumb. Tried that first thing but I had a typo. XD Thanks!